# The most frequent words in all dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset as below:

```
interests<-data.frame(interests=c("A mentor/teacher,Friendship",
                      "A play partner,Princess by day slut by night,Friendship,A sub,A slave",
                      "A relationship,A play partner,Friendship,Events",
                      "Not Defined"))
```

so the dataset is as below:

```
interests
<fctr>
A mentor/teacher,Friendship
A play partner,Princess by day slut by night,Friendship,A sub,A slave
A relationship,A play partner,Friendship,Events
Not Defined
```

I need to know, ***How many times each term is repeated in dataset?***

For instance the  **"Friendship"** has repeated *3* times, but the **"A play partner"** has reapeated *2* times, and the rest are repeated one.

I have seen the similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291984/find-the-most-frequently-occuring-words-in-a-text-in-r/37292306), but the issue is the length of the terms are differing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(interests$interests), split="\\W")))
```

or, since you seem to consider "A play partner" a single term:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(interests$interests), split=",")))
```