# I am wondering how to make a term document matrix of keywords consisting of several words in R

Tags: r, nlp

Is there a way to make a data frame like this into a term document matrix? Each keyword consists of two or more words.

#### Example data

Data type is a data frame.

```
doc_id text
1      c('cat dog', 'cat rat')
2      c('cat dog')
3      c('cat rat')
```

#### Desired result

I want to get this result. The TermDocumentMatrix function already exists does not reflect a multiword keyword.

```
         Docs
Terms    1 2 3
cat dog  1 1 0
cat rat  1 0 1
```

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput` ?

Comment: have you had a look here? https://www.tidytextmining.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute ngrams for each row of text data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556085/compute-ngrams-for-each-row-of-text-data-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr` and `tidytext` you first `unnest` the list column before replacing the white space with `_` (you can use something else but `_` is usually used to represent n-grams). This way the words are not separated when producing the tdm:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)

# bring toy data into useful form
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~doc_id, ~text, 
  1,      c('cat dog', 'cat rat'),
  2,      c('cat dog'),
  3,      c('cat rat')
)

tdm <- df %>% 
  unnest(text) %>% 
  mutate(text = str_replace(text, "\\s+", "_")) %>% # replace whitespace
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  count(word, doc_id) %>% 
  cast_tdm(word, doc_id, n)
tdm
#> <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 2, documents: 3)>>
#> Non-/sparse entries: 4/2
#> Sparsity           : 33%
#> Maximal term length: 7
#> Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

To display it as a regular matrix:

```
tdm %>% 
  as.matrix()
#>          Docs
#> Terms     1 2 3
#>   cat_dog 1 1 0
#>   cat_rat 1 0 1
```